# finding the correct Function arguments

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, arguments

I keep getting an error telling me that members needs an argument:

```
import random

def club_members(members):

    members=int(input("members"))
    print ("The winner is", + (random.randint(1, members))+ "congratulations")

club_members()
```

Error msg is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Python_Stuff\hockey 1.py", line 7, in 
>   club_members()
>
> TypeError: club_members() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'members'

Comment: It might help to add the specific error text you're getting and on which line the error occurs if your development environment provides this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a method called `club_members()` which accepts an argument `members`, but you invoke it without any parameters. That is why the interpeter is yelling at you. Instead, as you don't use that parameter anyway (you simply override it) you should make `club_members` parameterless:

```
def club_members():
    members=int(input("members"))
    print ("The winner is", + (random.randint(1, members))+ "congratulations")
```